# Ignored attemp to bind route Error in Sail.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, blueprint

I've just started to learn Sails.js and watching a lot of screencasts. By the way, when i'm trying to add a custom route like '/:screenname', i got this error:

"Ignored attempt to bind route (/:screenname) to unknown blueprint action (`findOne`)."

My routes.js is like this:

```
'GET /:screenname': {
    contoller: 'UserController',
    action: 'findOne'  
  }
```

And my UserController:

```
module.exports = {

    //GET /user/:id
    findOne: function(req, res) {

        User.findOne({
            screenName: req.param('screenname')
        }).exec(function(err, user) {
            if(err) return res.negotiate(err);

            //User.subscribe(req, user.id);
            res.view('profile', {
                user: user
            });
        });
    }
};
```

What could i do wrong? I realy couldn't find it, also on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is just bind your route to the controller like this:

```
  '/:screenname': 'UserController.findOne'
```

That should give you what you are looking for.

To dig a little more into what you are doing, the method you were using before is looking for one of the already generated blueprint actions. If you changed it to something like this what it would do is call the blueprint method 'find' with the parameter screenname.

```
  '/:screenname': {
    contoller: 'UserController',
    action: 'find'  
  }
```

findOne is not a blueprint action which is why you were getting that error.

Comment: There you go, in the screencast i was watching, they did like the one i wrote. It took 5 hours to solve this issue, thank you.